# Format object - number: delete gaps as separator and note

Tags: python, format, numbers

I have downloaded the table from the web to the dataframe. I have one column where the amount should be.

However, the column is formated as the "object" and the number is formatted with the gaps as the thousand separator, like "6 628 720 000". Moreover, some numbers are accompanied with the note, like "1)" or "4)" etc.

So the numbers actually look like:

```
"Amount |  6 628 720 0001) | 9 731 240 0004)" 
*, info: "0   Amount 4 non-null      object"*
```

The goal is to delete the gaps and delete the notes behind the numbers to look like:

```
"Amount |  6628720000 | 9731240000" 
*, info: "0   Amount 4 non-null      int-64"*
```

My idea was to delete "x" signs from right if you find ")" in the part of number (defined between right and the first gap from right) to narrow the number of signs in that part to 3. Then delete all "gaps". But unfortunately, I have not figured out how to make it in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Product': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'Amount': ["6 628 720 0001)","7 048 910 0002)", "1 436 000 000", "9 731 240 0004)"]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)   
print(df)
```

Comment: can you provide a mininal code that we can use?

Comment: yes. of course. Thank you        `import pandas as pd  
data = {'Product': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'Amount': ["6 628 720 0001)","7 048 910 0002)", "1 436 000 000", "9 731 240 0004)"]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
print(df)  `